# How to Rename C# files being moved from source to destination folders using prefix of directory name on each file?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

In `C#` while moving files from source to destination folders, how to rename the destination file with prefix of directory name to each file?

Answer (score 0):

static void Main(string[] args)
{

```
        string sourceFolder = @"C:\Source";
        string destinationFolder = @"C:\Destination\";
        string dirName = Path.Combine(destinationFolder, DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"));
        Directory.CreateDirectory(dirName);
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(sourceFolder);
        string searchXlsPattern = "*.xls*";
        try
        {
            //Getting list of files from Nested sub folders
            ICollection<FileInfo> files = di.GetFiles(searchXlsPattern, SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(file => !file.DirectoryName.Contains("Archive"))
            .Select(x => x)
            .ToList();

            if (files != null && files.Count() > 0)
            {
                foreach (FileInfo currentfile in files)
                {
                    if (new FileInfo(dirName + "\\" + currentfile.Name).Exists == false)
                    {
                        //Renaming old file name to new file Name
                        string fileDirectoryName = "";
                        fileDirectoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName(currentfile.FullName);
                        string replaceSlash = Convert.ToString(fileDirectoryName.Replace("\\", "_"));
                        string replaceSplChar= replaceSlash.Replace(":", "_");
                        string fileextension = Path.GetExtension(currentfile.Name);
                        string fname = currentfile.Name.Replace(fileextension, "");
                        string newFileName = replaceSplChar.ToString()+ "_" + fname + fileextension;

                        //Copy the file to destination folder 
                        //tempfile.CopyTo(Path.Combine(destinationFolder, newFileName), true);

                        //Move the file to destination folder
                        currentfile.MoveTo(dirName + "\\" + newFileName);
                        ////File.Move(currentfile.DirectoryName + "\\" + currentfile.Name, dirName + "\\" + newFileName);
                        //File.Move(currentfile.DirectoryName + "\\" + currentfile.Name, dirName + "\\" + newFileName);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
                Console.Write("There is no files in Source");

        }
        catch (IOException Exception)
        {
            Console.Write(Exception);
        }
    }
```